# How to invoke Javascript function when the route changes in .net 8 blazor web app?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, .net-8.0

I created a blazor web app with Auto Interactive Render Mode and Interactivity location is Component/Page using .net 8. I added a javascript function in script tag in the App.razor file to add some dynamic stylesheet in the head section. I invoke it on DOMContentLoaded event like this:

```
  function updateMood() {
    const linkElement = document.createElement('link');
    linkElement.rel = 'stylesheet';
    linkElement.type = 'text/css';
    const appMood = localStorage.getItem('appmood');
    if (appMood === "dark") {
        linkElement.href = 'css/darkmood.css';
    }
    else {
        linkElement.href = 'css/lightmood.css';
    }
    document.head.appendChild(linkElement);
  }
 // invoke the function
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    updateMood();
  });
```

The problem is when I change the route in my app using NavigationManger, the added stylesheets are removed and gets back to its initial state.

**How can I persist the change or invoke the javascript function when route changes?**

Note: I can't invoke the javascript function from every page's onAfterRender method, because there are some pages in the server project which can't invoke javascript functions.

Comment: This question looks extremely familiar.  Is it a repost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is probably with *Interactivity* location set to *Component/Page*, App and Routes are statically rendered on the server on every navigation.

However, you can manipulate the head section and thus the stylesheets using `HeadContent` without the need for JS.

The simplest way is to use two different layouts and then set the layout on the pages.

Dark Mode Layout

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<HeadContent>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="app1.css" />
</HeadContent>

<div class="page">
//...
```

You can also base it on the route.  I've added a cascade to `Routes` that cascades the `RouteData`.

```cs
<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly" AdditionalAssemblies="new[] { typeof(Client._Imports).Assembly }">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <CascadingValue Value="routeData" >
            <RouteView RouteData="routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(Layout.MainLayout)" />
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </CascadingValue>
    </Found>
</Router>
```

And then consume it in Layouts.  I've added a simple detection based on component type, but you could detect implementing an interface or an attribute.

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
<HeadContent>
    @if (_addCss)
    {
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="app1.css" />
    }
</HeadContent>

//...
@code {
    [CascadingParameter] private RouteData? routeData { get; set; }

    private bool _addCss;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _addCss = false;

        if (routeData?.PageType == typeof(Home))
            _addCss = true;
    }
```